# What is a purpose of using position relative on wrapper/container div element?

Tags: css, position

I am practicing HTML markup and CSS few months ago and now I'm quite understood about web design standards and layouts. I've seen many times on the source of other web layouts which they use position relative on their main Wrapper or Container div.. I want to know the purpose of utilizing this because there is no any physical/visual change appear on that wrapper div.. so what is the purpose behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/position

The relative position will tell the browser to "reserve" the space of the element in the normal document flow, and you can displace the said element in anyway without further affecting document flow (e.g. `left: -50%`).

Also, the relative position allows inner absolutely positioned children to be position relatively to this element. E.g., if the child element has an absolute position of `top: 50px`, it will be positioned relatively from the top border of the parent element (who is relatively positioned) by 50px, instead of from the `<body>` element.

Answer (score 3):

Using `position: relative;` on a container is done so `position: absolute;` on descendants will apply to the container element, not the `body`.

See the [`position`](http://learnlayout.com/position.html) page on learnlayout.com.